# Cross compiling: "user: Current not implemented on linux/amd64"

Tags: go, cross-compiling

I compile the following Go program on a linux/amd64 box:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/user"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(user.Current())
}
```

This works fine. But when I cross compile it from a Mac box, I get the following error when I run that program on my linux box:

`user: Current not implemented on linux/amd64`

How can I cross compile *and* use the Current function in package `os/user`?

---

Edit 1:
I should add that these are the instructions I've used to setup cross compiling on my Mac box: https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/WindowsCrossCompiling

---

Edit 2: cross compiling for windows/386 works fine.

Comment: Which Go version are you using? Which Linux?

Comment: @Volker I use `go version go1.2 darwin/amd64` and try to run it on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (`Linux xxx 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`)

Comment: i have the same issue, i have Linux Fedora 20, golang from RPM, `go version go1.2.2 linux/amd64` and has the same issue? i compile on linux for linux. How can i avoid this issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is due to [Issue 6376: user.Current panic in darwin-amd64 when crosscompiled from linux-amd64](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6376):

> os/user relies on cgo, and cgo is disabled for cross compiling,
>   thus this is expected.
>
> if you use os/user, you must compile natively on OS X.
>
> even if we enable cross compilation cgo support, I doubt everybody have
>   a working OS X cross toolchain on their linux machine.
>
> **Status: WorkingAsIntended**

Comment: Too bad I have to accept your answer ;-) Thank you very much.

Comment: In what realistic way can what Go does be called "cross-compiling"?